# Scala: akka http unmarshal xml strings to case classes

Tags: xml, scala, akka-http, scala-xml

I have a simple XML response from third-party API.

Let's say it looks like

```
<items>
    <item name="name1"/>
    <item name="name2"/>
    <item name="name3"/>
 </items>
```

Having a case classes

```
case class Items(children: List[Item]) 
case class Item(name: String)
```

How can I write unmarshaller to use implicitly which will work with code like this:

```
Unmarshal(myXmlString).to[Items].map ...
```

Or better

```
Unmarshal(myXmlString).to[List[Item]].map ...
```

Can I do it without defining any unmarshal functions which explicitly access XML? Data I already have looks declarative enough have unmarshalling without additional boilerplate.

Comment: I had same thoughts when I started using Spray (now akka-http) but quickly came to conclusion that writing such unmarshaller is not worth it because XML of different 3rd party services is way to different and scala-xml is not the best tool either. I ended up actively using JSoup to parse XML responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scala-xml doesn't provide any deserializer to hydrate your custom objects. 
If the requirement is simple as mentioned in the sample example, you can try something like this below:

```
    scala> val itemsString = "<items><item name='name1'/><item name='name2'/><item name='name3'/></items>"   
    scala> val itemsXml = scala.xml.XML.loadString(itemsString)                                              
    scala> val items = Items(( itemsXml \\  "@name").toList.map(( x=> Item(x.toString)) ))                               │
```